# HTML select tag with React - creating a select list of rendered elements from data array, but not recognizing the first element as a value

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, express, select

I created a `form`, where it has the `select` html tag.

I am fetching `users` from my MongoDB then updating `array` with fetched information, then rendering each `user elements` as the `select` tag drop menu's options.

The issue is that all the data is rendered as select tags element,
but if I choose the first option, it does not update the value but stays empty.

This is how my `select` part of form looks like:

```
<select ref={userInput}
  required
  className="form-control"
  value = {username}
  onChange={onChangeUsername}
>
  {userItem}
</select>
```

Here's `onChangeUsername` which is triggered on `onChange` event:

```
const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('')
const onChangeUsername = (e) => setUsername(e.target.value)
```

And this is how I render the `userItem`:

```
const userItem = users.map(user => <UserOption key={user} user={user}/>)
```

and this is the `UserOption` component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function UserOption({user}) {
  return (
    <option
      key={user}
      value={user}
    >
      {user} 
    </option>
  ) 
}
```

And it only does not recognize the first `option element` in the `select` menu.
I `console.log` the `post` request, and the `user` value is `""` if I choose the first option.
Any other option does pass its value.

Wonder what is the reason? and how to fix it?

Comment: check this, I made demo or your work
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-grothendieck-vinr1?file=/src/App.js

Comment: when you choose first user from dropdown, which is already selected by defualt, so there is no change event called, consequently, state of username = "" remains empty string.

Comment: To get this work, I added option with empty value which is state username = "", now when you select user first, the onChange event will be invoked and the username change to first user.